# each reload nextjs material ui style lost even add _app.js and _document.js of material ui nextjs github repository but still after reload style lost

Tags: next.js, material-ui

we try out many GitHub repositories to solve this issues but still not resolved,so please help me about how we can resolve this issue. Thank you

_app.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);
```

and my document file looks like this
_document.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
export default class MyDocument extends Document {

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head></Head> 
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
  ctx.renderPage = () => {
    return originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });
  };
  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what do you want to achieve with this code? As I can see in _app.js you remove the style with removeChild. Maybe you should clarify you question and provide more information. Generaly for basic MUI useage you don't need to modify you _app nor _document. Did you mean this github repo? https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs

Comment: @kepes is right. There is an element of removing the styles based on a condition and the logic exists in a useEffect hook meaning it runs once when the component mounts. In short please clarify your objective.